# How to save an invisible password inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'01': ['user01', 'lastname01', 'login01', 'pass01']...}
```

And I need to make all the passwords invisible, is there  way to do so?

Edit

I mean, if I print the dic, it should hide the pass, with an asterisc string or something like that.

Comment: Be more specific about "invisible" please. Who should not see it? For what reason?

Comment: No. If you're trying to roll your own encryption, you're probably doing it wrong, because [cryptography](http://blog.codinghorror.com/encryption-for-dummies/) [is](http://blog.codinghorror.com/top-25-most-dangerous-programming-mistakes/) [hard](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/).

Comment: Just don't print the dictionary. What is your use case that you fear that an unauthorized person can print or access this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt it, but there's no way to make the passwords 'invisible'. I would create a function to encrypt the password and another one to decrypt one. I suggest using Casers' Cypher if you're going for a basic encryption, but if you want you can look up some more advanced ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that hides the password. Assuming password is always the 4th element in the list:

```
usrdata = {'01': ['user01', 'lastname01', 'login01', 'pass01']}

def hidepass(data):
    newdata = data
    for key in data:
        newdata[key][3] = '*'*len(data[key][3])
    return newdata

print hidepass(usrdata)
```

Your output will be:

```
{'01': ['user01', 'lastname01', 'login01', '******']}
```